# get_pages Not accepting my query

Tags: themes

Im hoping someone maybe able to point out my mistake. I have a function in functions.php with a simple meta_query.

If I use this query.

```
$args = array(
'meta_query' => array(
  array(
   'meta_key' => 'Partner_Level',
   'meta_value' => 'Gold',
   'post_type' => 'page',
   'post_status' => 'publish' 
)));
$pages = get_pages($args);


foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
$option = '<option value="' . get_page_link( $page->ID ) . '">';
            $option .= $page->post_title;
            $option .= '</option>';
            echo $option;
}
```

I retrieve every page in my site, not the ones matching the $args passed to get_pages();

If I simplify the $args to

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'Partner_Level',
    'meta_value' => 'Gold',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
```

Then Im not getting any results at all.

So it really is an all or none, from what I can see my query looks good, but I know Im overlooking something, but what.... ? Appreciate any help with this.

I have performed a SQL statement and Im able to retrieve the expected results using..

```
$querydetails = "
   SELECT wposts.*
   FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
   WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
   AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'Partner_Level'
   AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'Gold'
   AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
   AND wposts.post_type = 'page'
   ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
 ";
```

So my assumption is its something with get_pages() not listening to my $args.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have pulled up stumps on this approach and gone back to my original function. It goes through the posts, looks for the Partner Level passed to it, and then retrieves a list of pages. I then display a styled list with the posts thumbnail as the clickable link. Will need to tweak for reach desired accessibility level, but thats for later. I appreciate your comments to this question.

For future reference:

```
function the_partners($cpLevel) {
global $wpdb;

 $querydetails = "
   SELECT wposts.*
   FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
   WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
   AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'Partner_Level'
   AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '$cpLevel'
   AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
   AND wposts.post_type = 'page'

   ORDER BY wposts.post_title ASC
 "; 

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querydetails, OBJECT);

echo "<ul class=\"logobox clearfix\">";
        foreach ( $pageposts as $page ) {
                $option = '<li>';
                $option .= '<a href="' . get_page_link( $page->ID ) . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID ) . '</a>';
                $option .= '</li>';
                echo $option;
        }
echo "</ul>";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you do `meta_query` there is no keys called `meta_key` or `meta_value` try using only `key` and `value`.

**Like This:**

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'page',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'meta_query' => array(
      array(
         'key' => 'Partner_Level',
         'value' => 'Gold'
      )
   )
 );
```

Let me know if this working. You will need to use [Appropriate Meta Compare](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) too.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I have tried key and meta_key both give the same result, I get a full list of all pages, not ones with the desired custom field key value combo..

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the comparison type as well. Try this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'Partner_Level',
            'value' => 'Gold',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
 );
```

Comment: Thanks for that, the compare didn't work either....